# Leer un CSV con pandas para una fecha determinada

Tags: python, pandas, date, csv, filtro

Tengo que leer y guardar un CSV con pandas a partir de una fecha determinada, pero el resultado no me devuelve lo que busco. Para ser más concreto, mi CSV origen contiene datos desde el 04/01/1999 hasta el 26/05/2022, pero lo que yo necesito es que me lea y guarde datos del 2015 en adelante.

El código que escribo es el siguiente:

```py
import pandas as pd
myfile = 'downloads/tipocambio/eurofxref-hist.csv'
tipo_interes = pd.read_csv(myfile, encoding='latin-1', header=0, decimal = '.')
tipo_interes[tipo_interes['Date']>='01/01/2015']
print(tipo_interes['Date'].min())
```

El cual me devuelve `1999-01-04`

¿Podríais ayudarme a saber qué estoy haciendo mal? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Una forma muy fácil de hacerlo es utilizar [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)

Como no pusiste los datos de tu `dataframe`, cree uno de prueba (Archivo sample.csv)

Que genera el siguiente `dataframe`

```
    fecha
0   2020-06-23
1   2020-04-23
2   2020-11-04
3   2022-01-24
4   1990-05-10
5   1995-04-07
```

En primer lugar debemos convertir la columna a `datetime`

```
df['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'], infer_datetime_format = True)
```

Y luego podemos filtrar con `timestamp`

```
df[df['fecha'] > pd.Timestamp(2015,1,1)]
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fecha'], infer_datetime_format = True)
df = df[df['fecha'] > pd.Timestamp(2015,1,1)]
print(df)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    fecha
0   2020-06-23
1   2020-04-23
2   2020-11-04
3   2022-01-24
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Ya me ha funcionado