# Filtrar un DataFrame por fecha

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, filtro

necesito filtrar mi dataframe para una fecha, concretamente necesito tener los datos para los que su fecha es mayor o igual a 31/01/2010. La columna que contiene la fechas es la columna 0 y es aqui donde creo que reside mi problema.

El código que escribo es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
balance_sector = balance_agregado.loc[(balance_agregado.columns[0] >= "31/01/2010")]
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:
KeyError: 'True: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'

También he intentado hacer los siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
balance_agregado[balance_agregado.columns[0]] = 
pd.to_datetime(balance_agregado[balance_agregado.columns[0]], 
infer_datetime_format = True)
balance_filtrado = balance_agregado[balance_agregado.columns[0]] >= 
31/1/2010
balance_sector = balance_agregado[balance_filtrado]
```

Pero da el error:
KeyError: "Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and float"

Y por último, he intentado hacer esto otro:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
balance_agregado[balance_agregado.columns[0]] = 
pd.to_datetime(balance_agregado[balance_agregado.columns[0]], 
infer_datetime_format = True)
balance_agregado[balance_agregado[balance_agregado.columns[0]]>= 
pd.Timestamp(2010,1,31)]
```

El resultado que me da, me saca fechas anteriores a 2010

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Leer un CSV con pandas para una fecha determinada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536894/leer-un-csv-con-pandas-para-una-fecha-determinada). Revisa la respuesta que puse en esa pregunta, creo que es lo que buscas, si no es así por favor dime que hace falta y con gusto te ayudo. Saludos

Comment: Hola, eso que me dices es lo que intento escribir en el ultimo script que indico en la pregunta, pero el resultado que me da saca fechas anteriores a la indicada

Comment: Copié y pegué el último código que tienes y lo probé con un `dataframe` de prueba, funciona correctamente, ¿Sería posible que arreglaste el problema al publicar tu pregunta? ¿Podrías incluir algunas líneas de tu `dataframe` con las que se pueda reproducir el error?

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he incluido saltos de linea en el codigo y me ha funcionado. Gracias!!