# Comparar dos formatos de fecha distintos en python

Tags: python, datetime

Tengo dos fechas en string con distinto formato ¿Cómo podría igualarlo a un mismo formato y comparar si son mismas fechas en python?

Formato 1: 2022-05-11 12:43:01.742685
Formato 2: 11/05/2022 12:43:01

Comment: Vas a tener que usar un parser de fechas como [dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/) que adivina los formatos de las fechas. Creo que pandas también tiene algun parser que adivina el formato.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Leer un CSV con pandas para una fecha determinada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/536894/leer-un-csv-con-pandas-para-una-fecha-determinada). Por favor revisa la respuesta, el parámetro `infer_datetime_format` sirve para eso.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el modulo [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) que reconoce la mayoría de formatos de fechas y los convierte fácilmente en datetime y a partir de ahi ya puedes crear tu formato deseado, por ejemplo:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

def iguala_formato(string):
    mi_formato= '%d/%m/%Y %X' # Día/mes/año tiempo
    dt = parse(string)    
    return dt.strftime(mi_formato)

print(iguala_formato("2022-05-11 12:43:01.742685"))
print(iguala_formato("2010-05-11 1:10:01.742685"))
print(iguala_formato("2010-05-11 12PM"))

# SALIDA
# 11/05/2022 12:43:01
# 11/05/2010 01:10:01
# 11/05/2010 12:00:00
```

Si no te interesa instalar el módulo, requieres construir un formato para cada formato de fecha existente, por suerte, en tu caso parece ser solo dos. El código seria algo asi:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def iguala_formato(string):
    formatos_soportados = [
        {
            "formato": "%d/%m/%Y %X",
            "ejemplo": "11/05/2022 12:43:10"},
        {
            "formato": "%Y-%m-%d %X.%f", 
            "ejemplo": "2022-05-11 12:43:01.742685"}
    ]
    
    mi_formato = "%d/%m/%Y %X"
    for formato in formatos_soportados:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(string, formato["formato"])
            return dt.strftime(mi_formato)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return None

print(iguala_formato("2022-05-11 12:43:01.742685"))
print(iguala_formato("11/05/2022 12:43:10"))
print(iguala_formato("2010-05-11 12PM"))

# SALIDA
# 11/05/2022 12:43:01
# 11/05/2022 12:43:10
# None
```